# Using a background image in pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

I've got a simple python file which opens up a `pygame` window. When I click and release within the window, the program will tell me where my cursor was when I started clicking and where I released it. How do I include code to have a background image in the `pygame` window? So far, I only how to do this programs as stand-alone.

```
import pygame, sys

LEFT = 1

running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 1000))


while running:
 screen.fill((0,0,0))
 pygame.display.flip()
 event = pygame.event.poll()
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
     running = False
     pygame.quit()

 elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
     print ("You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
 elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
     print ("You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following line to load an image:

```
my_image = pygame.image.load('my_image.png')
```

and then display it on the screen using the following line:

```
screen.blit(my_image, (x, y)) # screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 1000))
```

also note that x and y indicate the position of the top left of the photo.

Comment: I think I just did something similar just after posting my question, but thanks for the tip. Is there any way to use a pdf as the background image?

Comment: hmmm, never tried that before. you can always convert your pdf to jpg or png and then load it. maybe this website can help you: 
http://pdftoimage.com/